# c# Regex.Matches problems with multiple matches results

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use Regex.Matches and it seems to work in a different way to what I am used to with other languages like PHP. 
Here is what I am trying to do:

I want to get all forms from a particular webpage, but when I try to do the following

```
        String pattern = "(?i)<form[^<>]*>(.*)<\\/form>"; 
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(content, pattern );

        foreach (Match myMatch in matches)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(myMatch.Result("$1"));
        }
```

This code does not show anything even though there are three forms on that page. It seems that when I use (.*) it just skips everything till the end of the content.

Answer (score 1):

The `Regex` class makes the `.` operator **NOT** match \r and \n by default. Try replacing this:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(content, pattern );
```

with:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(content, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for the main portion of your Regex:

```
    String pattern = "<form[\\d\\D]*?</form>";
```

It is a pattern I am currently using to strip all tags of a specific type out of a document, but should do well finding the form tags. You can alter the \d\D section, if so desired.

Comment: This worked for me, but still this is really strange that c# just returns everything (single match) instead of all matches unless you try to 'trick' it.

Answer (score 0):

```
string pattern = @"(?is)<form[^<>]*>(.*?)</form>";
```

That regex should work the same in PHP and C# (or, more accurately, PCRE and .NET).  If you're getting minimal matches in PHP *without* the `?`, you probably have the `/U` ("ungreedy") option set, e.g.:

```
preg_match_all('~<form[^<>]*>(.*)</form>~isU', $subject, $matches);
```

or

```
preg_match_all('~(?isU)<form[^<>]*>(.*)</form>~', $subject, $matches);
```

.NET has no equivalent for PCRE's ungreedy mode.

Comment: Yes, I was using isU option in php. Thank you for your clarification.